# How to create a self signed certificate with a CA certificate containing the basic constraint extension with subject type as CA

Tags: c#, azure, ssl, openssl

I am attempting to create an application gateway using the azure rest api. I am using a self signed certificate that I generated using the following documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/self-signed-certificates

When I send the request to create the application gateway I get the following error:

does not contain any CA certificate. A CA certificate contains the basic constraint extension with subject type as CA.

I have attempted combining the root certificate with the client certificate but this does not seem to help.

The solution needs to be automated and will be running from a Windows Machine, here is the relevant source code(C#) that matches the documentation:

```
        Process process = null;
        var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        processInfo.FileName = AzureNames.OpenSSLBinaryLocation;
        processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        processInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory;
        
        processInfo.Arguments = string.Format("ecparam -out {0}.key -name prime256v1 -genkey", AzureNames.CertificateRoot);
        process = Process.Start(processInfo);
        process.WaitForExit();

        processInfo.Arguments = string.Format("req -new -sha256 -key {0}.key -out {0}.csr -subj \"/C=US/ST=Denver/L=Denver/O=Enterprise Architecture/OU=Enterprise Architecture/CN=site.com/emailAddress=sample@sample.com\"", AzureNames.CertificateRoot);
        process = Process.Start(processInfo);
        process.WaitForExit();

        processInfo.Arguments = string.Format("x509 -req -sha256 -days 365 --extensions v3_ca -in {0}.csr -signkey contoso.key -out {0}.crt", AzureNames.CertificateRoot);
        process = Process.Start(processInfo);
        process.WaitForExit();

        processInfo.Arguments = string.Format("ecparam -out {0}.key -name prime256v1 -genkey", AzureNames.CertificateClient);
        process = Process.Start(processInfo);
        process.WaitForExit();

        processInfo.Arguments = string.Format("req -new -sha256 -key {0}.key -out {0}.csr -subj \"/C=US/ST=Denver/L=Denver/O=Enterprise Architecture/OU=Enterprise Architecture/CN=site.com/emailAddress=sample@sample.com\"", AzureNames.CertificateClient);
        process = Process.Start(processInfo);
        process.WaitForExit();

        processInfo.Arguments = string.Format("x509 -req -in {0}.csr -CA  {1}.crt -CAkey {1}.key -CAcreateserial -out {0}.crt -days 365 --extensions v3_ca -sha256", AzureNames.CertificateClient, AzureNames.CertificateRoot);
        process = Process.Start(processInfo);
        process.WaitForExit();
        
        process.Close();

        //combine root cert into client certificate
        var rootContents = File.ReadAllText(AzureNames.CertificatesStorageLocation + @"\" + AzureNames.CertificateRoot + ".crt");           
        File.AppendAllText(AzureNames.CertificatesStorageLocation + @"\" + AzureNames.CertificateClient + ".crt", Environment.NewLine + rootContents);

        //perform manual step
        File.Copy(AzureNames.CertificatesStorageLocation + @"\" + AzureNames.CertificateClient + ".crt", AzureNames.CertificatesStorageLocation + @"\" + AzureNames.CertificateClient + ".cer");
        var userCommand = string.Format("openssl pkcs12 –export –in {0}.cer –inkey {0}.key –out {0}.pfx -passout pass:{1}", AzureNames.CertificateClient, AzureNames.CertificatePassword);
        Console.WriteLine("Open command prompt, then run the following two statements as seperate commands(copy paste)");
        Console.WriteLine("--------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("cd \"" + workingDirectory + "\"");
        Console.WriteLine(userCommand);
        Console.WriteLine("--------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("After you have successfully run the commands above:");
        Console.WriteLine("       1. Close the command prompt you just opened(not this one)");
        Console.WriteLine("       2. Press any key to continue");
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Continuing on...");
```

Comment: It looks like you've been using SO for around 9 years... and haven't "accepted" any responses yet.  Even your own solutions :)  Who knows - maybe my response will be a first :)  In any case, you can *DEFINITELY* do better than a bunch of "Process.Start()" commands ;)

Comment: @paulsm4 I haven't accepted any answers because no one answered my questions.  I cannot accept your answer as it does not solve the problem.  Utilizing a windows process is irrelevant to the question as the certs already generate correctly from an open source library called openSSL.  The question is how to set the constraint subject type to CA.  Your adendum might prove to be helpful however the certificate is being generated for another machine so installing it locally is less than ideal.

Comment: Your current solution isn't only clumbersome - it doesn't work.  Lose it, and substitute a method that DOES work.  PowerShell scripts and C#/.Net apps will allow you to generate a self-signed certificate with the correct extensions (your original question), as well as copy it wherever you want (an additional requirement you didn't mention until now).  Both work on Windows and/or Azure.  PS: Over the years, you answered at least one of your OWN questions.  But failed to "accept", leaving the question "Open".

Comment: @paulsm4 I was able to resolve the issue.  I'm still not sure why you think openSSL is not an acceptable solution when Microsoft recommended it.   I could move the commands into a bat or ps1 but I would still need to kick it off from starting a process in C#.  That seems irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern openSSL utilizes a required .cnf file for the functionality mentioned in the original Tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/self-signed-certificates

Change the second openSSL process

```
processInfo.Arguments = string.Format("req -config {1} -new -sha256 -key {0}.key -out {0}.csr -subj \"/C=US/ST=Denver/L=Denver/O=Enterprise Architecture/OU=Enterprise Architecture/CN=site.com/emailAddress=sample@sample.com\"", AzureNames.CertificateRoot, configFile);
```

Add the required configFile.cnf

[req]

req_extensions = v3_req

distinguished_name = dn

[dn]

[v3_req]

basicConstraints = CA:TRUE

Then Change the third openSSL process

```
processInfo.Arguments = string.Format("x509 -req -sha256 -days 365 -extensions v3_ca -extfile {1} -in {0}.csr -signkey contoso.key -out {0}.crt", AzureNames.CertificateRoot, configCAFile);
```

Add the required configFileCA.cnf

[v3_ca]

basicConstraints = CA:TRUE

Answer (score 1):

All your C# code is doing is spawning shell processes to run "x509" and friends.

SUGGESTION: Since your environment is MS Windows/MS Azure, try this instead:

> [PS PKI:
> New-SelfSignedCertificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pki/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=windowsserver2022-ps)
>
> New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "www.fabrikam.com",
> "www.contoso.com" -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\My"

You can specify any number of extensions (by OID), including:

> The object identifiers of some common extensions are as follows:
>
> ```
> Application Policy. 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.10
> Application Policy Mappings. 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.11
> Basic Constraints. 2.5.29.19
> Certificate Policies. 2.5.29.32
> Enhanced Key Usage. 2.5.29.37
> Name Constraints. 2.5.29.30
> Policy Mappings. 2.5.29.33
> Subject Alternative Name. 2.5.29.17
> ```

See also:

- [Generate self-signed certificates with the .NET CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/self-signed-certificates-guide)
- https://adamtheautomator.com/new-selfsignedcertificate/

---

ADDENDUM:

You can also generate a self-signed certificate directly in C#:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.certificaterequest?view=net-6.0

This fully supports Certificate extensions:

> [X509Extension Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509extension?view=net-6.0)
>
> ```
> using System;
> using System.Security.Cryptography;
> using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
>
> public class CertSelect
> {
>     public static void Main()
>     {
>         try
>         {
>             X509Store store = new X509Store("MY", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
>             store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
>
>             X509Certificate2Collection collection = (X509Certificate2Collection)store.Certificates;
>             for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++)
>             {
>                 foreach (X509Extension extension in collection[i].Extensions)
>                 {
>                     Console.WriteLine(extension.Oid.FriendlyName + "(" + extension.Oid.Value + ")");
>
>                     if (extension.Oid.FriendlyName == "Key Usage")
>                     {
>                         X509KeyUsageExtension ext = (X509KeyUsageExtension)extension;
>                         Console.WriteLine(ext.KeyUsages);
>                     }
>
>                     if (extension.Oid.FriendlyName == "Basic Constraints")
>                     {
>                         X509BasicConstraintsExtension ext = (X509BasicConstraintsExtension)extension;
>                         Console.WriteLine(ext.CertificateAuthority);
>                         Console.WriteLine(ext.HasPathLengthConstraint);
>                         Console.WriteLine(ext.PathLengthConstraint);
>                     }
>
>                     if (extension.Oid.FriendlyName == "Subject Key Identifier")
>                     {
>                         X509SubjectKeyIdentifierExtension ext = (X509SubjectKeyIdentifierExtension)extension;
>                         Console.WriteLine(ext.SubjectKeyIdentifier);
>                     }
>
>                     if (extension.Oid.FriendlyName == "Enhanced Key Usage")
>                     {
>                         X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension ext = (X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension)extension;
>                         OidCollection oids = ext.EnhancedKeyUsages;
>                         foreach (Oid oid in oids)
>                         {
>                             Console.WriteLine(oid.FriendlyName + "(" + oid.Value + ")");
>                         }
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>             store.Close();
>         }
>         catch (CryptographicException)
>         {
>             Console.WriteLine("Information could not be written out for this certificate.");
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```